# Можно ли как-то пометить поле input?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте. У меня в форме на JavaScript есть динамическое добавление поля `input` в форму.
Новое добавленное поле имеет следующие атрибуты:

```
<input value="<?=$prp['name'];?>" name="prpunkt[]<?=$ipp?>" type="text" />
```

где **$prp['name']** - текст из базы.
**$ipp** - `$ipp++`;

Задача такая, нужно сделать редактирование уже имеющихся полей в базе, и добавление новых.

И все бы ничего, но. Каждое поле привязывается к определенной статье.
Структура таблицы с полями:

> id - `AUTO_INCREMENT`
>
> trip `INT` - *id статьи к которой привязываем поле*
>
> name `varchar` - *значения поля (текст в поле)*

К статье может быть привязано неопределенное кол-во полей.

При редактировании статьи, есть возможность редактировать уже имеющиеся доп. поля и создавать новые.

Уже имеющиеся поля, при редактировании статьи я вывожу циклом:

```
while ($prp = mysql_fetch_assoc($option_prp)) {
            $ipp++;
            //echo $ipp;
    ?> <div><input class="stationinppp" value="<?=$prp['name'];?>" name="prpunkt[]<?=$ipp?>" type="text" /></div> <?
        }
```

То есть, получается что, если к этой статье добавлено, например, 3 доп. полей, разметка получается такой:

```
<input value="<?=$prp['name'];?>" name="prpunkt[]1" type="text" /> 
<input value="<?=$prp['name'];?>" name="prpunkt[]2" type="text" />
<input value="<?=$prp['name'];?>" name="prpunkt[]3" type="text" />
```

А новое добавленное поле имеет разметку:

```
<input value="<?=$prp['name'];?>" name="prpunkt[]4" type="text" />
<input value="<?=$prp['name'];?>" name="prpunkt[]5" type="text" />
```

Меняется значение **name** - `name="prpunkt[]+1"`

вопрос, каким образом мне определить на сервере, какое поле было изменено, а какое поле было добавлено?
это мне для того чтобы выполнять соответствующие запросы в базу, на новое поле **INSERT INTO** - запись новой строки в базу / на измененное поле **UPDATE** - обновление записи.

Данные из полей на сервере отлавливаю так:

```
foreach ($_POST['prpunkt'] as $k => $f) {
        echo $_POST['prpunkt'][$k];
}
```

Comment: сразу вопрос.. почему нельзя воспользоваться в БД `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно какой-нибудь пример с этим?

Comment: эм... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html ? или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=INSERT+ON+DUPLICATE+KEY+UPDATE выбирайте... смысл как раз в том, чтоб установить уникальный ключ в БД на поле (поля) и при запросе вида INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY  - новые записи добавились, а старые (если совпадают с теми, что в запросе) проапдейтились

Comment: @АлексейШиманский **mysql_query("INSERT INTO `prom_item` (`trip`, `name`) values('$nw_id', '$namepp')
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='$namepp'");** поле **name** уникальным сделал. но при редактировании поля добавляется новое. Что я упускаю?

Comment: Всмысле "добавляется новое"? Если вы добавили уникальность на name то там не может появится ещё 1 запись с темже name.

Comment: Кстати, расширение mysql удалено из php7.

Comment: @Arnial дублирующее поле и не появляется в базе. появляется новое, с другим значением `name` . У меня в форме динамическое добавление полей input. И вот, на странице редактирования статьи, если есть добавленные доп. поля, их выводит, чтобы их можно было отредактировать. и если отредактировать уже имеющееся поле - старое остается, а в базу добавляется отредактированное, и получается что у статьи теперь и старое поле и новое